# Is it possible to use both Kite and You Complete Me (auto completions) on VIM editor

Tags: python, c++, vim, autocomplete, kite

I want to use auto-completion both for C++ and python. After research, I found that Kite is better at python but doesn't have a C++ integration on vim. Is there a way to say:

use YCM on .cpp files
&
use Kite for .py files?

Answer (score 1):

Kite supports C++ in vim and neovim all you have to do is to enter in below lines in your vimrc or init.vim after installing kite autocompletion engine.

```
" All the languages Kite supports"
let g:kite_supported_languages = ['*']

" For tab key completions"
let g:kite_tab_complete=1
```

Also you can check on [their github page](https://github.com/kiteco/vim-plugin).

Kite supports all c family langs ...
here we are struggling with Rust.